# How is azerbaijan characters insert in mssql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I have a program written using C# and wpf.I want to insert azerbaijan character to Mssql from this program but '?' character is showing in row. Mssql datatype is nvarchar(50). How am I do?

```
  public void YeniLiderEkle(string LiderAdi, string sifre, int Admin){
BakuBusCenterDBDataContext db = new BakuBusCenterDBDataContext();
            Liderler liderler = new Liderler();
            liderler.AdiSoyadi = LiderAdi;
string a1 = StringReplace(LiderAdi.Replace("  "," ").Replace("   "," ").Trim().ToLower()).Split(' ')[0];
             string l=a1.Split('_')[1].Substring(0,1);
            liderler.KullaniciAdi = a1.Split('_')[0]+l;
            db.Liderlers.InsertOnSubmit(liderler);
            db.SubmitChanges();
           }
```

And true word "sdəhr" but showing "sd?hr" from Mssql

Comment: For literal strings, you need to prefix the literal with `N` to denote a Unicode string. But it is better to use parameterized queries with data type nvarchar.

Comment: Show us your code. We can't tell you why it isn't working if you don't show us. What do you mean by the "Azerbaijan" character, the flag emoji? 

Answer (score 0):

For inserting `varchar` values you should wrap them with `'` like `'Hello'`, for `nvarchar` you should also use `N` before the wrapping `'` chars: `N'Yaşasın Azerbaycan'`.